# Is it possible to run the zend complete project without setting virtual host?

Tags: zend-framework

I have created a zend project and executed it through a virtual host... so is it possible to run a zend project without creation of virtual host?

Comment: of course, why would think otherwise?

Comment: it's very possible, just inconvenient.

Comment: can you people exaplain that process?

Comment: You mean to say via command-line or what?

Comment: In any way i just want to execute zend project without virtual host

Answer (score 0):

Just generate your project using Zend_Tool as always and update the public/index.php to the correct path and voila, you don't need a virtual host, but it's always recomended since it makes things more transparent.